# Dynamic sqlReaderQuery in azure data factory using powershell

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

I am new to data factory and powershell. Looking a way to provide user input to the sqlReaderQuery as a where clause.
So that user can select a subset of data from sql server and push it azure sql.
I can see the parameters for date and time values but I am looking to provide ID with date.
Is there a way to write powershell to pass these values to the pipeline.

Any help is highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sqlReaderQuery in Azure Data Factory is unfortunately not very dynamic; the only variables that are really available are SliceStart, SliceEnd, WindowStart, and WindowEnd. You can tweak these with functions like AddDays and so on but that is not really going to do what you want I don't think.
One option with PowerShell is to generate a new pipeline JSON file based on your users input and use New-AzureRmDataFactoryPipeline to add that JSON to your data factory as a new pipeline. Of course this will mean you'll have a lot of pipelines unless you use Remove-AzureRmDataFactoryPipeline.
Another option would be to use a Stored Procedure activity. Your user input could be saved in the database and the stored procedure would then dynamically create the extract to another table.